# Get midpoint of SDE.ST_GEOMETRY polylines?

Tags: sql, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, centroids, st-geometry

[image]

I have a polyline SDE.ST_GEOMETRY feature class in an Oracle 12c geodatabase (10.7.1).

I want to create a view on the feature class that has X and Y columns that contain the coordinates of the polyline midpoints.

---

I've noticed that while there is a [centroid function](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-centroid.htm) for polygons, there [isn't](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/a-quick-tour-of-sql-functions-used-with-st-geometry.htm) a midpoint function for polylines.

Is there a way to get midpoint coordinates of SDE.ST_GEOMETRY polylines with SQL?

Comment: `ST_CENTROID()` is documented as finding the center of the bounding box of the minestrone (which might not be on the line, unless it's a 2-point segment)

Comment: @Vince What's the minestrone part about?

Comment: linestring, as rendered by autocorrect

Comment: Assuming your linestrings don't change frequently, pre-computing the location for each geometry midpoint using a geodetic function with a GIS client, and storing this as a point with a common key should be simple enough.

Comment: Seems like you need a `ST_LineInterpolatePoint( geom, 0.5)` equivalent for an oracle database.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Yeah, the equivalent exists in Oracle Spatial, but not SDE.ST_GEOMETRY.

Comment: @Vince : Well, this changes things! [Spatial now free with all editions of Oracle Database](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclespatial/spatial-now-free-with-all-editions-of-oracle-database).

Answer (score 1):

The custom ST_MIDPOINT function below works.

However, it's horrendously inefficient because it doesn't seem to be possible to use the SDE functions & operators to directly assign values to variables. I needed to wrap them in queries instead.

More information here:
[Use SDE.ST_GEOMETRY functions in a custom function](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344294/use-sde-st-geometry-functions-in-a-custom-function)

---

```
-- execute this as the SDE user
create or replace function ST_MidPoint
   (line_in IN sde.st_geometry)
   RETURN sde.st_geometry
IS midpoint sde.st_geometry;
  srid integer;
  line_length number(38);
  num_parts integer;
  num_points integer;
  partNum integer;
  distanceAlong number(38);
  segmentLength number(38);
  part sde.st_geometry;
  p1 sde.st_geometry;
  p2 sde.st_geometry;
  x1 double precision;
  y1 double precision;
  x2 double precision;
  y2 double precision;
BEGIN
  -- get the SRID of the line for later use in constructing the midpoint geometrey
  select sde.st_srid (line_in)
  into srid
  from dual;

  -- calculate the total length of the line
  select sde.st_length(line_in)
  into line_length
  from dual;

  -- get the number of parts that make up the line
  select sde.st_numgeometries(line_in)
  into num_parts
  from dual;

  distanceAlong := 0;
  for partNum in 1..num_parts loop
    --dbms_output.put_line(partNum);
    -- get the geometry for this part
    select sde.st_geometryn(line_in, partNum)
    into part
    from dual;

    -- get the number of points that make up this part
    select sde.st_numpoints(part)
    into num_points
    from dual;
    --dbms_output.put_line(num_points);

    -- get the first point (the "from" point) for the part
    select sde.st_pointn (part, 1)
    into p1
    from dual;

    -- iterate along the line until the section that contains the midpoint is found
    for pointNum in 2..num_points loop
      -- get the "to" point of the segment
      select sde.st_pointn(part, pointNum)
      into p2
      from dual;

      -- calculate the distance between the from point and the to point
      select sde.st_distance(p1, p2)
      into segmentLength
      from dual;

      -- add the distance along this segment to the running total
      distanceAlong := distanceAlong + segmentLength;
      --dbms_output.put_line(distanceAlong);
      -- check to see if the running total is past the midpoint
      if distanceAlong >= line_length/2.0 then
        -- the two current points encompass the midpoint of the line
        -- determine the midpoint geometry and return it
        select sde.st_x(p1)
        into x1
        from dual;
        select sde.st_y(p1)
        into y1
        from dual;
        select sde.st_x(p2)
        into x2
        from dual;
        select sde.st_y(p2)
        into y2
        from dual;
        select sde.st_point((x1+x2)/2.0, (y1+y2)/2.0, srid)
        into midpoint
        from dual;
        -- the midpoint has been found, not need to interogate the rest of the line
        RETURN midpoint;
      end if;
      -- save the endpoint as the first point and continue down the line looking for the midpoint
      p1:=p2;
    end loop;
  end loop;

  return null;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END;
/
grant execute on ST_MidPoint to public;


--select objectid,sde.ST_MidPoint(shape) geom
--from gis.line_test
--order by objectid;
```

---

A better option would be to have a nightly python job that precomputes the midpoints in a parallel feature class:

[Insert geoprocessing results into an existing feature class (midpoints)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/345110/135445)

Comment: There are a couple answers over here that are better: [Get midpoint of SDO.GEOMETRY polyline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59261247/get-midpoint-of-sdo-geometry-polyline).